# Expected ";" at the end of declaration list

Tags: objective-c, syntax

Have been thinking about what's wrong with my code below. All of the methods declaration are quoted by XCODE as errors. it said Expected ";" at end of declaration list. I would appreciate your help. Thanks :)

```
    @interface
    Budget : NSObject{

float exchangeRate;
double budget;
double exchangeTransaction;


- (void) createBudget: (double) aBudget withExchangeRate: (float) anExchangeRate;
- (void) spendDollarts: (double) dollars ;
- (void) changeForeignCurrency: (double) foreignCurrency ;
    }
    @end




    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
         NSLog(@"Run Without error");
         return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `}` in the wrong place.  It needs to be right after `exchangeTransaction`. Example:

```
@interface Budget : NSObject 
{
    float exchangeRate;
    double budget;
    double exchangeTransaction;
}

- (void)createBudget:(double)aBudget withExchangeRate:(float)anExchangeRate;
- (void)spendDollars:(double)dollars;
- (void)changeForeignCurrency:(double)foreignCurrency;

@end
```

Comment: I included my method declaration inside instance variable declaration. So, what's the difference between using "};" and only "}". because both are compiled fine.

Comment: I don't understand that question, sorry.

Comment: Sorry. I mean in the example you provided. on the line 6th, there's a curly bracket ended with ";". if I remove the ";" from there and it's compiled too. No error sign from Xcode. Just like no difference between put ";" or omit it.

Comment: Oh, it's probably not necessary then.  Sorry - I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Once again thanks mate. :) you're so helpful.